# redux Store does not have a valid reducer coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6, redux

First time working with Redux and I understand the concepts of Actions and Reducers but cannot get them to play nicely in my code and I'm worried it's because I'm using CoffeeScript instead of ES6.

I *think* the issue is I can't do the `export default ...` in my */app/reducers/index.coffee* but honestly Redux is very new to me and I've been stumbling along with webpack and react for a while and am still not the most comfortable with either, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I keep getting the error:

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
```

*/app/actions/index.coffee*:

```
{ FETCH_ITEMS, FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM } = require('../constants')

fetch_items = ->
  { type: FETCH_ITEMS }


fetch_single_item = (id) ->
  {
    type: FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM,
    id: id
  }

module.exports = { fetch_items, fetch_single_item }
```

*/app/reducers/items.coffee*:

```
$ = require('jquery')
{ FETCH_ITEMS, FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM } = require('../constants')
{ fetch_items } = require('../actions')

INITIAL_STATE = []

items = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) ->
  console.log action.type
  switch action.type
    when FETCH_ITEMS
      console.log 'FETCH_ITEMS'
      $.get "http://dosomething.com/items", (resp) ->
        console.log resp
    when FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM
      console.log 'do something'
    else
      console.log "suckit turk!"
  state

module.exports = { items }
```

*/app/reducers/index.coffee*:

```
{ combineReducers } = require('redux')
items = require('./items')

reducers = combineReducers({ items })

module.exports = { reducers }
```

and finally */app/index.cjsx*

```
React        = require("react")
ReactDOM     = require("react-dom")
{
  createStore,
  combineReducers,
  appyMiddleware
} = require('redux')

{ reducers } = require("./reducers/")

STORE = createStore combineReducers({ reducers, routing: routerReducer     })
HISTORY = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, STORE)

STORE.subscribe () ->
  console.log STORE.getState()

...omitted react render: ->...
```

**EDIT**

Sorry everyone, yes routeReducer is defined, I just omitted it because I'm pretty sure that it's not the problem.

*/app/index.cjsx*

```
React        = require("react")
ReactDOM     = require("react-dom")
{
  createStore,
  combineReducers,
  appyMiddleware
} = require('redux')

{
  syncHistoryWithStore,
  routerReducer
} = require('react-router-redux')


{ reducers } = require("./reducers/")

STORE = createStore combineReducers({ reducers, routing: routerReducer     })
HISTORY = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, STORE)

STORE.subscribe () ->
  console.log STORE.getState()

...omitted react render: ->...
```

Comment: Is this error thrown in `index.coffee` or `index.cjsx`? Also, where is `routerReducer` defined in `index.cjsx`?

Comment: CoffeeScript never was a good idea and now is an even worse idea :/

Comment: thanks @mash for being absolutely no help what-so-ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reducer must:

1. Receive a state and an action as argument
2. Always return the same or a new state.

Your "reducer" `items` only appears to return a state in case none of the cases in the `switch` statement match, which means it is not a valid reducer. If you are encountering this error when you emit one of those actions, redux could detect that a new state hasn't been returned. See whether you still encounter this issue after making `items` a proper reducer.

#### Side Note

You are making an asynchronous API call from your `items` reducer, and your stub code looks like you are planning to add a second one. This is not the correct use of a reducer; the store should hold data pertaining to your application state, and a reducer should manufacture a new state given an old state and an action type and/or payload.

Instead, call these sorts of asynchronous functions in an "action creator". [(See docs.)](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html)

An action creator like `fetch_items` will execute the AJAX request, and on success trigger a dispatch of a `set_items` action, e.g. `{ type: 'SET_ITEMS', payload: [...response.items...] }`. Your reducer will listen for the `SET_ITEMS` action and return a new state, updated with the payload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply this-vidor I edited the post above, I am requiring  `routeReducer` and `syncHistoryWithStore` and the error is happening in index.cjsx. When I log out `reducers`, I get `function combination() { ... }`

Comment: @Sparkmasterflex Updated.

Comment: Thank you again @this-vidor, that was totally it and thanks for the additional help.

Comment: @Sparkmasterflex Glad this got you running! The [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) sets out some good best-practices for writing reducers: pure functions, no side-effects. They should always return the same output, given the same inputs. Try to minimize computation in the reducer itself— it's a triage layer between actions (which express an intent to change state in a precise way) and the state itself.